# Dependency Property has a value set upon control construction

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

We're in WinRT XAML.

I have a custom control `B` with a dependency property `Items`, the control is in a template for another control. The dependency property is initialized to an new empty collection using the `PropertMetadata` type. It is never data-bound - keep that in mind.

When I enter the page, the control is instantiated as part of the template for another custom control `A`. From a breakpoint in the constructor for `B`, when I check the value of `Items`, it contains 0 items.

As part of other activity, control `A` 'manually' calls `B.Items.Add()` to insert data. There is no data-binding.

When I navigate backward and then click to navigate to the page again, the constructor is again fired but this time `Items` still has the values that `A` added. It retains its value.

So even though the control is unloaded and loaded (I can see the events), the control and dependency property is not reinitialized.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dependency property is declared as a static field in your class `B`. It is initialized exactly once and hence the new collection in the property metadata is initialized only once and later shared by all "instances" of the property. This is a common mistake made in dependency property declarations.

You should set the dependency property value to a new empty collection in the constructor of class `B` instead of providing a default value by property metadata.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't think its right. The property metadata should be applied to 'new instances'. "The most common metadata given for dependency properties is to give them a default value that is applied on new instances that use the property." - MSDN. I smell a bug, to be honest. Something doesn't feel right with this one.

Comment: That's definitely not a bug and has been discussed a few times here on SO. The default value provided by property metadata is just assigned to the property in every new instance of your control. You can simply test this by creating two instances of your custom control at the same time and check the `Items` value. It will be the same collection object, namely the one you provided as default value.

Comment: Got it, you're right. http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2010/02/11/be-careful-with-default-values-of-dependency-properties-if-youre-using-reference-types/